# PHP: strtotime()... again

Tags: php, string, parsing, format, strtotime

How do I have to write "+3 days at 12:34:56" to make strtotime() parse it properly?

Comment: In my example I would like to have the timestamp for today at 12:34:56 plus three days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ts = strtotime("12:34:56 +3 days");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s O', $ts);
```

prints

```
2009-09-23 12:34:56 +0200
```

(my local timezone is CEST/gmt+2)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I got it: I just had to remove the "at":
"+3 days 12:34:56" parses, yay!

Answer (score 0):

personally I'd do something like this:

```
date("Y-m-d 12:34:56",time()+(60*60*24*3))
```